# Selenium, WebDriver Manager, and Electron Desktop Apps

Tags: selenium, electron, webdriver-manager

I'm building out some ui automation tests for an electron app. I have an existing test framework built in C# using Selenium and Appium for web and mobile devices.
I figured out how to start the chrome driver and target the electron app, but to do so, I had to not use the extremely handy WebDriverManager package.

This is my set up

```
        [SetUp]
        public void TestSetUp()
        {
            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new()
            {
                BinaryLocation = @"ElectronApp.exe",
            };

            _driver = new ChromeDriver(@"local driver path", chromeOptions);

        }
```

This works to open up the electron app using Chrome driver. I did have to match the version of Chrome the electron app used and made sure to download that version of the webdriver.

What I want to know is if there's a good way to use WebDriver Manager to set up my driver, but open the electron app.

This was what I was trying:

```
        [SetUp]
        public void TestSetUp()
        {
            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new()
            {
                BinaryLocation = @"ElectronApp.exe",

            };

            ChromeConfig chromeConfig = new();
            new WebDriverManager.DriverManager().SetUpDriver(chromeConfig, "98.0");
            _driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

The 98 is the version of Chrome that the electron app is apparently using -- that's the same version I had to match the driver for.

This is the stack error:

```
  Message: 
System.Net.WebException : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

  Stack Trace: 
HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
WebClient.DownloadBits(WebRequest request, Stream writeStream)
WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
BinaryService.DownloadZip(String url, String destination)
BinaryService.SetupBinary(String url, String zipPath, String binaryPath)
DriverManager.SetUpDriverImpl(String url, String binaryPath)
DriverManager.SetUpDriver(IDriverConfig config, String version, Architecture architecture)
DesktopTests.TestSetUp() line 41
--TearDown
DesktopTests.Teardown() line 54
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was so focused on the WebDriver Manager, I missed that the chrome version I was specifying wasn't valid. Instead, I used the full version, and it worked great.

```
    [SetUp]
        public void TestSetUp()
        {
            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new()
            {
                BinaryLocation = @"ElectronApp.exe",

            };

            ChromeConfig chromeConfig = new();
            new WebDriverManager.DriverManager().SetUpDriver(chromeConfig, "98.0.4758.102");
            _driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
    }
```